# How to use an angular component in every other component?

Tags: javascript, angular

I've been trying to use a component  in some other component which are in their respective hierarchies but unable to do so.

I have a component "TestComponent" in app directory which i want to use in different other components.

For this:

```
<app-test></app-test>
```

but i am getting errors:

```
1. If 'app-test' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'app-test' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

and when i try to import in components separately, it is throwing error that the component is already in use.

Comment: Please make sure that you have added TestComponent as a reference in app.module.ts. Also add a declaration in imports array in app.module.ts.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kundan said, you have to declare the TestComponent in your app.module.ts. Every component you generate must be declared in a module. So your declarationsarray in app.module.ts should look like this:

```
    import {TestComponent} from './path'
    @NgModule({
    declarations: [ // here you declare your components
    TestComponent,
    ..] 
    })
```

A little sidenote. Once your application gets bigger, its reccomended to use lazy loaded modules. So you can have multiple modules which all declare their "own" components. But a component **must** be declared only once.